# Upgrade Google Play services in Android emulator

Tags: android-emulator, google-play-services

I'm trying to upgrade Google Play Services on an android emulator AVD. The AVD version I'm using is the Nexus 6 API 22 x86 with Google APIs. The error I'm getting in logcat in the emulator is

```
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ Google Play services out of date.  Requires 7895000 but found 6774470
```

My application shows a dialog box titled "Update Google Play services", with text

> Robo test App won't run unless you update Google Play services.

An Update text button is also shown.

Clicking on it generates more errors in the emulator

```
E/SettingsRedirect﹕ Can't redirect to app settings for Google Play services
```

I've download a later APK version of Google Play services and tried installing using

```
./adb install -r ~/work/com.google.android.gms-7.8.99_\(2134222-470\)-7899470-minAPI21.apk
```

but I get the following error

```
1937 KB/s (47783328 bytes in 24.080s)
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.google.android.gms-7.8.99_(2134222-470)-7899470-minAPI21.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE]
```

My build.gradle file contains

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':Library')
    compile 'com.netflix.rxjava:rxjava-android:0.20.7'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.8.0'
    provided 'org.roboguice:roboblender:3.0.1'
    provided 'junit:junit:4.11'
    provided 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.4'
}
```

My dev machine OS is OSX 10.10.5, running jdk 1.8u40.
My Android Studio version is 1.3.1

Can anybody suggest anything else I can try?

Comment: I think you should try to update your emulator in `SDK manager` to the latest one with Google APIs

Comment: Hello. I am using the latest one. The android 6 (API Level 23) doesn't have any Google API support.

Comment: Have you tried delete the emulator and import it again?

Comment: I've deleted all the AVDs,the SDK Tools and Android Studio. I then did a clean install of Android Studio and the SDK tools.

Comment: I have a nexus 6, but I thought it might be faster to do simple UI testing in the emulator

Comment: If you wanna a fast emulator, which i often used was Genymotion. You can try it if you want. and [here](https://gist.github.com/jbj88817/8f464a33269a48811d5d) is to add play service for that.

Answer (score -1):

> One thing which worked for me was that I opened play store, signed up and then manually upgraded the "Google Play Services" app.
>   Check out this answer for more info : https://www.stackoverflow.com/a/35498283

Hope this helps !