# error: Please update your Google Play service in Android emulator (version should be 10.2.0)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I have downloaded a sample project. It requires 10.2.0 Play service, so I can't change the compile version in the build.gradle to lower version.

I have followed the other SO questions:

[Android Studio with Google Play Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16624827/android-studio-with-google-play-services)
[How to update Google Play Services for Android Studio 2.2 emulators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37798911/how-to-update-google-play-services-for-android-studio-2-2-emulators)
[updating Google play services in Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35476182/updating-google-play-services-in-emulator)

I have also downloaded the latest Google Play service, install the necessary SDKs, clean build project, sync Gradle, use API 24 and API25 for my emulators.

None of it works, my Play service is still using 10.0.8. Below are the screenshots of my Android Studio settings.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Delete the emulator, and in the SDK manager, also delete the SDK platform on which that emulator was built.

Then, re-download that SDK platform and re-build your emulator.

Why?

If there have been updates to Google Play Services since you've downloaded said SDK platform and built that emulator, the legacy version of Google Play Services is probably still in that SDK platform's build.