# Google Play services version on emulator is old and it shouldn't be

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-play-services

I just upgraded Google Play services SDK from android package manager. The current package revision is 39. According to the version history, this package should include Google Play services version 10+. However, I get 9.8 on my emulator.

http://www.smorgasbork.com/2015/01/05/google-play-services-sdk-version-history/

[Google Play services version in emulator and package manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qc68w.png)

After updating the package, I removed the old emulator and created a new one. No success.

How should I get the most recent version?

Comment: Can you open the Play Store and go into settings, Then tap on ( Play Store version ) 5-7 times.... It should force an update check !

Comment: There is no Play Store in the emulator. AFAIK the only way to update the Play Services is via package update. I did this, but version is still older.

Comment: Wrong image attached above, here is the right one:
http://1.1m.yt/OewolyM.png

Comment: You might want to check the solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37798911/5995040), they tried using the API 24 64 image and not the 86 and tried checking for updates both android studio and Google Play Service. Don't forget to restart the Android Studio and create a new AVD. Hope this info helps.

Comment: Hi, thank you, this solved my problem!