# Unable to resolve "App won't run unless you update the google play services" error for version 9.8.79

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services

I'm working on using the google maps api for an android application but I keep on getting the "App won't run unless you update the google play services" error.

I recently installed the latest version of google play services maps (version I believe 10.2.99)

by adding the line

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.99'
```

to my gradle build file dependencies and clicking on the "Install repository and sync project" seen in the message window which prompted the download.

I apparently needed to install the version being used on my emulator device which is version 9.8.79 (because that's the version running on the emulator device)

So far:
I've tried updating the gradle dependencies to

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.8.79'
```

But the "Install repository and sync project" button wont register a click and I haven't been able to resolve the dependency that way

I've tried downloading a new sdk to see if that would change the google play services version number I need

and

I've tried to import the module by downloading the library but http://www.apkmirror.com/uploads/?q=google-play-services doesn't have that version of the play services library.

I'm officially stuck and would love any help

edit 
   I tried setting the line to 
`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:+` 
   and no dice

I also tried updating sdk for my play services right before this post and that also didnt help

here is my gradle build

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {

compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "teamplaceholder.com.placeholderapp"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta5'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.8.79'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

I was able to fix the error by updating the play services for the emulator as Alvi and Ahamed suggested by downloading a Nexus 5 x86_64 and API 24 emulator and using that(emulator suggested in [How to update Google Play Services for Android Studio 2.2 emulators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37798911/how-to-update-google-play-services-for-android-studio-2-2-emulators/41803959#41803959)). I also needed to clear the play services cash once I ran the emulator by going into settings->storage->apps->GooglePlayServices and pressing "clear cash"

Thanks a ton for all the help

Comment: try to set it like this 
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:+'

Comment: I think you need to update your play service for your emulator.
Try this: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Comment: Please post your build.gradle.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update Google Play Services for Android Studio 2.2 emulators?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37798911/how-to-update-google-play-services-for-android-studio-2-2-emulators)

Comment: The thing is you are going to use Google service. so you need to update the Google play services in your virtual or physical device

Comment: @Ahamed thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @Alvi sorry if I misunderstood your initial comment, thanks for the suggestion it helped a ton