# MapFragment doesn't work because of Google Play Services Failure

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-play-services

I have a MapFragment that I dynamically display in my Activity.

But It says that I have to update Google Play Services. I've done this by updating the Dependencies, but it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Heres my Gradle file:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.0'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'
```

}

My Fragment:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="ibas.locatix_teamviewer.mapFragment">

<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

And here is my Activity:
[image]

Comment: You said you updated dependencies, but have you updated GAPPS? http://stackoverflow.com/q/34291902/4012979

Answer (score 0):

The google play-services version on your device is out of date. Just click the update-button, and you will be able to download the newest version on your device from the play-store.

Edit:
There are [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35476182/updating-google-play-services-in-emulator) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37798911/how-to-update-google-play-services-for-android-studio-2-2-emulators/41803959#41803959) like this on Stackoverflow.
You might find these questions and answers useful.

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) your emulator should also use Android 4.2.2 or above.

> To test your app when using the Google Play services SDK, you must use either:
>
> - A compatible Android device that runs Android 4.0 or higher and includes Google Play Store.
>
> -The Android emulator with an AVD that runs the Google APIs platform based on Android 4.2.2 or higher.

Comment: When i click "update" the application crashes... What to do?

Comment: @skm which device have you got an which Android version?

Comment: On my Own Device (Samsung s6) it works fine but in the Emulator (AVD) it just shows this information that the playservices have to be updated...when i click update it crashes.