# Android Studio emulator extremely slow

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have Android Studio updated at latest release (today is April 22nd, 2017) and Haxm installed, but the Android emulator is completely useless. It is extremely slow.

I don't know why, a few days ago it was running fast and smooth. Then I restarted my computer and it became extremely slow. It must be some reason for this.

Please, do not answer to install Genymotion. Genymotion doesn't allow me to emulate the phone in the free version.

As I said, intel haxm is installed.

The message "Process system isn't responding" is displaying all the time.

---

**UPDATE April 25th, 2017**:
My Android Studio installed a new update (I cannot specify what got updated) and now the emulator suddenly runs fast again (the same AVDs, I haven't created new ones)
But this same behavior has happened before. I am sure that in a few days/weeks it will suddenly run extremely slow again, and it will be this way for a few days/weeks, after another update will run smooth again. This has been happening for me during months.
I will post here when that happens.

---

**UPDATE April 30th, 2017**:
My Android Studio installed a new update (Google Repository) and now the emulator suddenly is going extremely slow (the same AVDs, I haven't created new ones). I am sure that in a few days/weeks it will suddenly run fast again.

Comment: Might be helpful [Why is the Android emulator so slow? How can we speed up the Android emulator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/why-is-the-android-emulator-so-slow-how-can-we-speed-up-the-android-emulator?rq=1)

Comment: Where is this message appearing? What operating system are you running the emulator on? What AVDs have you tried? Have you tried deleting and re-creating the AVD? Have you tried re-restarting the computer?

Comment: I have tried with Android 6.0, 7.0 and 7.1. I am on windows 10. I have restarted the computer several times. I have been days this way. I cannot believe I am the only one

Comment: can you check if the CPU/ABI profile in your emulator is selected as x86 and not arm

Comment: It is x86. Thanks

Comment: @Ton you aren't the only one. I feel your pain. And it's exactly the same in my case. Some weeks it's great and some weeks the emulator is unusable. Switching to Software - GLES 2.0 helped slightly but still nowhere near what it is on a "good" week.

Comment: Yes, you're not alone. I'm having the same issue. Looking for answers.

Comment: In my case switching to 86_64 version of the CPU/ABI profile solved the problem!

Comment: check [this updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35498283/2826147)

Answer (score 6):

Finally I've found a solution (at least to me). I've followed this steps (I don't know if all of them are necessary):
1) Manually updated HAXM to last version from Intel website
2) As my laptop has 2 integrated GPU's (Intel and Nvidia, where Intel is the default and weaker one), in Nvidia GeForce control panel, I've forced both emulator.exe and qemu-system-i386.exe to use Nvidia card instead Intel.
3) I've created new AVD's with x86 image and setup the GPU to use "Hardware - GLES 2.0" profile.

Now the emulator is incredibly fast. It seems better than never.

Answer (score 4):

In my case the problem was (and still is) the emulated graphics settings (see AVD / Virtual Device Configuration), probably indicating a problem with video card and/or video driver. I had very random speed using *Automatic* or *Hardware - GLES 2.0* - sometimes it's silky smooth, sometimes it's unacceptable. (On a side note: I find these  issues only on Android 6.0+ emulator, for example Android 4.1 is always very fast).

After switching to ***Software - GLES 2.0*** performance is now acceptable: not very fast, but usable, and also the color gradients are not as nice (it's software rendering after all). I hope it works for you too.

Comment: Today April 30th, 2017, the emulator is running slow again so I tried your "Software - GLES 2.0" solution. I agree with you, it is acceptable. At least I can test my apps in "slow days". Before it was impossible. But besides I really appreciate your help, I don't believe this should be the "accepted" answer to my question.  Again thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm glad it helps on "slow days" :) I agree it's not a solution, merely a workaround. I found this thread in the meantime, it might be relevant in your case: https://issuetracker.google.com/u/0/issues/37139095
It's a long and ongoing thread, main message is that Windows 10 updates, Intel HD 4000 and Android Emulator doesn't play well together - some patch seems to cause the problem, some other seems to fix it for some people..

Comment: That link you provided is very interesting. Thanks

Comment: Solution for me was trashing Avast. Thanks for the link Attila Mate.

Comment: @AttilaMate can You share some screenshots where this configuration is located?

Answer (score 1):

After experiencing the exact same issue and reading the other comments in this thread it dawned on me that attempting to run twin monitors and an emulator on a laptop with an Intel HD Graphics 4000 chipset might be too much for the chip.

I removed the second monitor and restarted Android studio and the problem disappeared immediately. I can now run the emulator at full speed with the "Hardware - GLES 2.0" setting.

and thinking back this problem started around the same time I replaced my old 17 inch secondary display monitor with a far larger 25 inch flat panel. I think the solution for me will be to go and find an smaller display with a lower resolution.

Comment: I felt second screen problem as you by intel 3000, it seem android studio emulator has problem with high resulution and with multi screens!

Comment: I haven't tested this, but I will say giving up a monitor just to the run emulator is a no-go for me, I rather just `xkill` every time I'm done with it.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43725534/3982001) of Márcio Oliveira, but in only one step: on my laptop with 2 integrated GPUs from `Nvidia Control Panel` -> `Managed 3D Settings` I forced the `qemu-system-i386` application (located in \AppData\Local\Android\sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64) to run on the Nvidia processor, this resolved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just update Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator(HAXM installer) to lastest version from studio

It really make change.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced similar issue, even though I haven't got low end computer it took up to 15 minutes when my virtual device come alive and then it was extremely slow. After a lot of googling I found this solution:

> Go to control panel - find Programs and Features - Turn on or off
>   Windows Features - checked Windows Hypervisor Platform.

After some installation (and maybe restarting your computer) your virtual device should work properly