# Android Studio Emulator BRUTALLY slow

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, emulation, android-virtual-device

I know this is a common question, but I feel like I've tried every single solution out there, so I don't know what to do anymore.

- Intel x86 HAXM is installed
- Tried Reinstalling the emulator in the SDK Manager
- Tried various AVDS with different API levels

Whenever I start my AVD, it will take about 10 minutes for the android sign to pop up, then it will remain for another 10 minutes and then eventually say the process has stopped. Sometimes it will launch and run fine, but it seems the initial startup just takes a brutally long time to the point where it's not worth to test any apps on it.

I don't understand what's wrong, and have been extremely frustrated with this situation over the past 2 days, any help or tips would be appreciated!

Comment: `... brutally slow...` :D

Comment: What are the specs of the system you are using, and is it 64-bit or 32-bit OS?

Comment: check [this updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35498283/2826147)

Answer (score 0):

Install Genymotion, Every single device/API version they host is relatively quick [GenyMotion Android Studio Plugin](https://www.genymotion.com/plugins/)

Answer (score 0):

visit [Why is the Android emulator so slow? How can we speed up the Android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/why-is-the-android-emulator-so-slow-how-can-we-speed-up-the-android-emulator)

Try low settings for faster open up Recommended 
1. use intel system image
2.Screen size 5.0 or below 
3. Ram size from android 5.0 is 1gb and above. if you have 4GB ram. 
4.Increase Ram size on your computer or laptop default 4Gb and above for faster run

Answer (score 0):

The emulator's performance has a lot to do with your specs and the specs of the emulator itself. I used to face the same problem, but I upgraded my ram and emulators of all types run pretty fast now. Another alternative is to use your device to test. As far as geny motion is concerned, it turned to be slow too. Its just my personal observations though.