# cannot install google play services 7.8.95

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, google-play-services

The emulator says that I need to update the google play services to run the apps and I found out that the emulator google play services version are 7.8.95 so I changed mine to 7.8.95 and it says Error:(25, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.95 so I Install Repository and sync project and its says

```
Ignoring unknown package filter 'extra-google-m2repository'Warning: The package filter removed all packages. There is nothing to install.

     Please consider trying to update again without a package filter.
```

How to fix this?

i used the emulator from android studio and this is my gradle code

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.lenovo.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.95'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
}
```

}

Comment: Are you use [genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) emulator or emulator _from android studio_?

Comment: Can u show the gradle code ?

Comment: this seems similar to this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35476182/updating-google-play-services-in-emulator).

Answer (score 0):

you need to update google play services and repository from SDK manager and clean and build your project after sync finished.

Comment: i already has the latest google play services and repository in sdk manager the latest one is 10.2.4 but since the google play services in my emulator is 7.8.95 which one to download in sdk manager to get the 7.8.95 version

Comment: which emulator you are using Genymotion or android predefined emulator ?

Comment: android predifined emulator

Comment: thats also doesnt works like i said in my previous comment 

   
i already has the latest google play services and repository in sdk manager the latest one is 10.2.4 but since the google play services in my emulator is 7.8.95 which one to download in sdk manager to get the 7.8.95 version

Comment: you need to user lower version define in your dependencies  just like compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.2.42' ,  i use in my system like this compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'

Comment: i already did that with 7.8.95 but...   it says Error:(25, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.95 but when i want to install that specific version. this error comes up

 Ignoring unknown package filter 'extra-google-m2repository'Warning: The package filter removed all packages. There is nothing to install.

     Please consider trying to update again without a package filter.

Comment: can u please try in your physical device?

Comment: yes i just tried its works really great in my actual phone no problem at all its a bit more tedious since i have to use gradle assemble to make unsign apk then transfer those apk to my phone through cable data every time i want to test my apps and i tooks quite a long a time to produce an unsign apk in my old laptop