# Using Google Service's FusedLocationProviderClient in a Tablet Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-play-services

I need to emulate an Android Application on a tablet. I'm currently running Android Studio 3.0.

The problem is that the application uses Google Service API's FusedLocationProviderClient ([Documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderClient)), which, as far as I understand, requires Google Services 11 as minimum. The current SDK tools for Android Studio seems to only update Google Play Services to 10.9.*, and it seems that no pre-configured Tablet emulators come pre-installed with Google Play Store, meaning I can't simply update it through the settings page the same way that you can with the new phone emulators that has play store pre-installed.

I've tried to find ways to manually update Google Play Services to the newest one available, however almost all previously accepted answers on here seems to simply suggest downgrading build.gradle dependencies to whatever the emulator supports. That doesn't work in this case however, as I need features specifically in the newer versions :/

Is there any way that one can manually update Google Play Services on an emulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No mention of what you're saying in the link you provided. However, it was announced [here](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/08/some-updates-to-apps-using-google-play.html) that if you're going to use Google Play Services 11.2.0, your app's `compileSdkVersion` must be at least `26`.

I would suggest that you go to Android SDK Manager and update your API package there. It often includes the System Image for emulators.
You can see on this screenshot that I'm able to use the Android emulator with Android 27 installed because I downloaded it first in the SDK Manager.

*I'm able to use API 27 because I installed the system image in SDK Manager:*
[image]

*from SDK Manager, API 27 package is downloaded and installed, hence it's available on the emulator:*

[image]

You can also check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35476182/updating-google-play-services-in-emulator) for additional reference.