# How to get the Android System Images that include the Play Store app?

Tags: android

According to [this announcement](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/12/quick-boot-top-features-in-android.html) I should be able to see Android images that include the Play Store. But, I cannot.

What am I doing wrong?

These are my recommended images. None of them include the Play Store.

[image]

and my x86 images. None of them include the Play Store.

[image]

I have pressed the refresh button. These are it.

I have tried a bunch of these images, but none of them gives me the Play Store:

[image]

Somehow, google manages to get the play store in some of their virtual devices:

[image]

My downloaded SDKs are:

[image]

Comment: See if you have an option for it in the SDK Manager. Click the "show package details" checkbox to see what emulator images the SDK Manager knows about.

Comment: Oh, I had not seen that checkbox. Looks promising. Trying...

Comment: Nope. The "Google Play Intel x86 Atom System Image" was not checked. I checked it, downloaded it, went back to the AVD manager and my list of available images is still the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're correct that the Google Play Store is only available for Nexus 5 and 5x emulated devices. However, I didn't see the "Select Hardware" screen among the screenshots that you posted.

At the bottom of the AVD "Your Virtual Devices" screen, click "Create Virtual Device". This should take you to this "Virtual Device Configuration" screen.

[image: screenshot]

If you scroll down the list of hardware, you should (hopefully) see Nexus 5 and 5x devices with the Play Store icon (as shown in the screenshot). Click one of these and continue with the rest of the configuration as normal.

Answer (score 1):

A comment in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35476182/updating-google-play-services-in-emulator/35496184) told me that Google Play only appears if one chooses a Nexus 5 or Nexus 5x as the device. That was it.

Somehow, Google has it running on a Google Pixel (as per the image above), but I guess they have not made that image available to us.