# how to fix: Google Play services out of date. Requires 12210000 but found 10298470

Tags: java, android-studio, admob

i am applying ads on my applications using android studio 3.0
but when i run the application it give this notification in Run Panel

> Google Play services out of date.  Requires 12210000 but found 10298470

help me fixing this problem

Comment: Provide an example of what you have tried so far and refer on how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example - 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 3):

You are requiring services 12.0.0 in your build.gradle file, but the emulator or device has an out of date google play services. If you are using an emulator, you need to use an emulator with Google Play so that you can update the services version. https://stackoverflow.com/a/35498283/3962777