# Error ImmutableJarInput after update google play service to 15.0.0

Tags: android, google-play-services

After update library Google play service (and firebase too) to 15.0.0, I get error like this:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unexpected inputs:    ImmutableJarInput{name=com.google.android.gms:play-services-location-license:12.0.1, file=/home/hahn/MyAndroidApp/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/99.jar, contentTypes=CLASSES, scopes=EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES, status=REMOVED},
ImmutableJarInput{name=com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone-license:12.0.1, file=/home/hahn/MyAndroidApp/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/116.jar, contentTypes=CLASSES, scopes=EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES, status=REMOVED},
ImmutableJarInput{name=com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:12.0.1, file=/home/hahn/MyAndroidApp/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/108.jar, contentTypes=CLASSES, scopes=EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES, status=REMOVED},
ImmutableJarInput{name=com.google.android.gms:play-services-base-license:12.0.1, file=/home/hahn/MyAndroidApp/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/103.jar, contentTypes=CLASSES, scopes=EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES, status=REMOVED},
ImmutableJarInput{name=com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1, file=/home/hahn/MyAndroidApp/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/94.jar, contentTypes=CLASSES, scopes=EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES, status=REMOVED},
ImmutableJarInput{name=com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-license:12.0.1, file=/home/hahn/MyAndroidApp/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/120.jar, contentTypes=CLASSES, scopes=EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES, status=REMOVED},
ImmutableJarInput{name=com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:12.0.1, file=/home/hahn/MyAndroidApp/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/111.jar, contentTypes=CLASSES, scopes=EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES, status=REMOVED},
ImmutableJarInput{name=com.google.firebase:firebase-common-license:12.0.1, file=/home/hahn/MyAndroidApp/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/93.jar, contentTypes=CLASSES, scopes=EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES, status=REMOVED},
ImmutableJarInput{name=com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:12.0.1, file=/home/hahn/MyAndroidApp/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/104.jar, contentTypes=CLASSES, scopes=EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES, status=REMOVED},
ImmutableJarInput{name=com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:12.0.1, file=/home/hahn/MyAndroidApp/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/117.jar, contentTypes=CLASSES, scopes=EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES, status=REMOVED},
ImmutableJarInput{name=com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement-license:12.0.1, file=/home/hahn/MyAndroidApp/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/107.jar, contentTypes=CLASSES, scopes=EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES, status=REMOVED},
ImmutableJarInput{name=com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:12.0.1, file=/home/hahn/MyAndroidApp/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/112.jar, contentTypes=CLASSES, scopes=EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES, status=REMOVED},
ImmutableJarInput{name=com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:12.0.1, file=/home/hahn/MyAndroidApp/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/105.jar, contentTypes=CLASSES, scopes=EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES, status=REMOVED},
ImmutableJarInput{name=com.google.firebase:firebase-iid-license:12.0.1, file=/home/hahn/MyAndroidApp/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/119.jar, contentTypes=CLASSES, scopes=EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES, status=REMOVED},
ImmutableJarInput{name=com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:12.0.1, file=/home/hahn/MyAndroidApp/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/97.jar, contentTypes=CLASSES, scopes=EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES, status=REMOVED},
ImmutableJarInput{name=com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps-license:12.0.1, file=/home/hahn/MyAndroidApp/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/100.jar, contentTypes=CLASSES, scopes=EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES, status=REMOVED},
ImmutableJarInput{name=com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-base:12.0.1, file=/home/hahn/MyAndroidApp/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/113.jar, contentTypes=CLASSES, scopes=EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES, status=REMOVED},
ImmutableJarInput{name=com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl-license:12.0.1, file=/home/hahn/MyAndroidApp/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/96.jar, contentTypes=CLASSES, scopes=EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES, status=REMOVED},
ImmutableJarInput{name=com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:12.0.1, file=/home/hahn/MyAndroidApp/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/109.jar, contentTypes=CLASSES, scopes=EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES, status=REMOVED},
ImmutableJarInput{name=com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:12.0.1, file=/home/hahn/MyAndroidApp/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/115.jar, contentTypes=CLASSES, scopes=EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES, status=REMOVED},
ImmutableJarInput{name=com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-license:12.0.1, file=/home/hahn/MyAndroidApp/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/98.jar, contentTypes=CLASSES, scopes=EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES, status=REMOVED},
ImmutableJarInput{name=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-license:12.0.1, file=/home/hahn/MyAndroidApp/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/95.jar, contentTypes=CLASSES, scopes=EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES, status=REMOVED},
ImmutableJarInput{name=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.1, file=/home/hahn/MyAndroidApp/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/102.jar, contentTypes=CLASSES, scopes=EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES, status=REMOVED},
ImmutableJarInput{name=com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-base-license:12.0.1, file=/home/hahn/MyAndroidApp/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/101.jar, contentTypes=CLASSES, scopes=EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES, status=REMOVED},
ImmutableJarInput{name=com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:12.0.1, file=/home/hahn/MyAndroidApp/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/118.jar, contentTypes=CLASSES, scopes=EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES, status=REMOVED},
ImmutableJarInput{name=com.google.firebase:firebase-common:12.0.1, file=/home/hahn/MyAndroidApp/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/106.jar, contentTypes=CLASSES, scopes=EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES, status=REMOVED},
ImmutableJarInput{name=com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:12.0.1, file=/home/hahn/MyAndroidApp/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/110.jar, contentTypes=CLASSES, scopes=EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES, status=REMOVED},
ImmutableJarInput{name=com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks-license:12.0.1, file=/home/hahn/MyAndroidApp/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/114.jar, contentTypes=CLASSES, scopes=EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES, status=REMOVED}
```

But when i change library version back to 12.0.1 my app running normally. 
Any idea to solve this problems?

EDIT: 
ok, after rebuild, this error gone. But when running application in emulator, I get error like this in logcat:

```
E/DialogRedirect: Failed to start resolution intent
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=market://details?id=com.google.android.gms&pcampaignid=gcore_12451000-d-id.myapp.app-19 flg=0x80000 pkg=com.android.vending }
    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1936)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1615)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4472)
    at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi16.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:54)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:68)
    at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.startActivityForResult(ActivityCompat.java:233)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityFromFragment(FragmentActivity.java:830)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks.onStartActivityFromFragment(FragmentActivity.java:939)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.startActivityForResult(Fragment.java:1021)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.startActivityForResult(Fragment.java:1010)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzd.redirect(Unknown Source:10)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.DialogRedirect.onClick(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Emulator said I need to update the google services, but when I clicked on the message, it's nothing happened.

Comment: Try to clean and then rebuild your project

Comment: done, and now my app successfully build. But when run to emulator, I get error and can't login with google account (must update google play services)

Comment: Check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35476182/updating-google-play-services-in-emulator/35496184

Answer (score 10):

i faced the same problem and just did

```
Build -> clean project
```

and run again works fine