# Google play services error in Emulator kitkat API level 19

Tags: android, google-maps, android-emulator, google-play-services, apk

I am using android studio 3.1. I am using Android 4.4  API 19 Nexus 5 Android emulator. I am using Maps in my app so when I run the app it showing Play services are updating and the app automatically closes since my app is related to map.

I have gone through a question like that and I have tried all the set of methods there. I have failed on it.

How can I update the Google Play services for above API level?

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35476182/updating-google-play-services-in-emulator Have u tried this ?

Comment: @Sathiyakugan yes I have tried all the method proposed on that question .

Comment: Which version of the Google Play services SDK are you using? I.e. which play-services-map version?

Comment: Hi, did you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try Updating Maps in Your Emulator manually if Possible. I had the Same

Comment: API level below  24 has no play store in the emulator.