# Setting up Firebase with android studio for authentication

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am trying to setup my android project with Firebase so that I can allow users to login and sign up for my app.
I have connected my app to Firebase but when I try and add Firebase Authentication to my app I get the following error:

> The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-base is being
>   requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.1,15.0.1]], but
>   resolves to 16.0.1. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies
>   tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.

Comment: Please add the content of your both build.gradle files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating both all the Play Services and Firebase libraries to the latest version. For more information take a look at https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#may_23_2018

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Updating Play Services has been discussed before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35476182/updating-google-play-services-in-emulator

To update firebase, you can just change the dependency version to the latest in your build.gradle